# Jupyter kernel dies while running this neural networks code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

img = image.load_img("image_location_here")

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('image_location_here', target_size = (50,50),  batch_size = 3,
  class_mode = 'binary')

validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('image_location_here', target_size = (50,50),batch_size = 3,
class_mode = 'binary')     
                         
train_dataset.class_indices

train_dataset.classes

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation = 'relu', input_shape = (50,50,3))` `tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu')

tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)

tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation = 'relu')

tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

The code above runs fine, but when I run the line given below the kernel dies.

`model().compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrices = ['accuracy'])`

I have updated anaconda to the latest version, restarted it few times still the kernel dies on this specific line.

sorry for the poor editing of the lines

Comment: That's not sufficient context and you can format multiple lines of code with 3 backticks at a line before and after the block

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. The issue is being caused by CUDA/cudNN, probably because you are using an incompatible version with Tensorflow. There are two solutions for the same:

1. Uninstall CUDA and reinstall Tensorflow library
2. Uninstall CUDA and setup the compatible CUDA/cudNN version ( Check https://tensorflow.org/install/source_windows for the version you need for your tensorflow version)